# How to compare lists and get most frequent pairs efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, list

I have many lists and I want  to compare them and get top pairs. If two distinct numbers exist together in a list they are pair.

List 1 => 1 4 5 6 0 7

List 2 => 2 3 8 6 1 9

List 3 => 4 7 1 3 5 6

**Pairs**

1,6 - 3 times (list1 , list2 , list3)  **Top Pair**

1,5 - 2 times (list1 , list3)

4,5 - 2 times (list1 , list3)

2,3 - 1 times (only list2)

**How to do this efficiently?**

**Note:** There is no same number in a list. All numbers are distinct in a list.

Comment: what have you tired && what does 'pair' mean in this context?

Comment: what programming language do you want this in?

Comment: how do you define a "pair"? I.e. doesn't the pair "1,5" appear twice in List 1, since 5 appears twice? Can the lists contain arbitrary numbers or is there a limited range of possible numbers?

Comment: I think a 'pair' means 2 values (it usually does) and I suppose they have to be distinct (but its a good question)

Comment: @soulcheck for example; 1 and 6 exists in each list together. I mean 1,6 is a pair and this pairs exists in 3 times.

Comment: Why isn't 7,5 a top pair? It appears twice (so more often than 2,3).

Comment: @M4N , this values are just samples. I corrected the header above pairs.

Comment: Is number of lists small? e.g if you have k list and each list size is n, then 2^k < n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the lists as sets. To better match the usage, first sort all lists and remove duplicates (or use a set data structure, if available).

Generate all pairs from each set, counting the occurrences in a hash table with the pairs as keys and integers as values. Generation can be done by a simple nested loop. Sort the keys by the values in the hash table.

Comment: I updated the question. There aren't any same values in each list. You can assume this list as set.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution.

Sort each list and convert into a 10 bit binary number

*e.g*

List one

```
  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
  N  N  Y  Y  Y  Y  N  N  Y  Y  = 243
```

List Two

```
  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
  Y  Y  N  Y  N  N  Y  Y  Y  N  = 846
```

List Three

```
  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
  N  N  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  N  Y  N  = 250
```

Pre-generate all the possible values for pairs

*i.e*

```
 0,1 = 3
 0,2 = 5
 ...
 1,5 = 34
 ...
 5,7 = 160
 ...
 8,9 = 768
```

Create a list of the values and counts (I've included text representation of pair for ease)

*e.g.*

```
public class Details {
    public string Pair { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

// selection only
public readonly static List<Details> PairDetails = new List<Details>() {
    new Details{Pair = "0,1", Value = 3},
    new Details{Pair = "0,2", Value = 5},
    new Details{Pair = "1,5", Value = 34},
    new Details{Pair = "1,6", Value = 66},
    new Details{Pair = "2,3", Value = 12},
    new Details{Pair = "4,5", Value = 48}
};
```

then iterate through the pairs and lists

```
foreach (var details in PairDetails) {
    foreach (var value in values) {
        if ((value & details.Value) == details.Value) {
            details.Count++;
        }
    }
}

var most = PairDetails.Where(dtls => dtls.Count == PairDetails.Max(dt => dt.Count)).ToList();
```

This will give you a list of all pairs which occur the most amount of times in the lists.

hth,

Alan.